# Orange (Data Mining) : How to start using "Orange" from Python Anaconda Environment?

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, orange

I have install "Orange Data Mining v3.4.1" in Anaconda Python v3 environment using commands : "conda install orange3" sucessfully.

However, I do not know how to call "Orange" as Application to start using it. There is also NO icon on the desktop as well.

Please help. Thank you very much in advance

Regards
Pearapon S.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instructions can be found on their Github page: https://github.com/biolab/orange3#starting-orange-gui

Short Answer:
In the conda env run orange-canvas
or
python3 -m Orange.canvas. Add --help for a list of program options.